# Which original Persian poem of Rumi does this refer to?

Tags: poetry, identification-request, persian-language, rumi

Does anyone know which is the Persian text for the below poem by Rumi ?

> I choose to love you in silence…
> For in silence I find no rejection,
>
> I choose to love you in loneliness…
> For in loneliness no one owns you but me,
>
> I choose to adore you from a distance…
> For distance will shield me from pain,
>
> I choose to kiss you in the wind…
> For the wind is gentler than my lips,
>
> I choose to hold you in my dreams…
> For in my dreams, you have no end.

See [I choose to love you in silence…](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/3239983-i-choose-to-love-you-in-silence-for-in-silence) on Goodreads.

Comment: After hours of searching in his Persian poems, I'm convinced that this is not Rumi's. (Not 100% sure though).

Answer (score 1):

This is the original text:

من دوست داشتم تو را در سکوت دوست بدارم ، زیرا هیچ انکار نمی شود. من دوست داشتم تو را در تنهایی دوست داشته باشم ، زیرا در آن تنهایی فقط به من تعلق داری. بوسه هایی را که به تو می دهم به باد رها می کنم. باد آنها را به ارمغان می آورد با من ملایم تر از من دستهای تو را در رویاهایم می گیرم.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Thanks for this answer! Could you provide some additional information? Where in Rumi's works is this found? Is there a title? Can you provide a link to where it is available online? That would make the answer more useful.

Comment: Using Google translate on this text, it looks very much like this is the correct answer.